# Tips on filtering two dimensional array

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Here is an example JSON:

```
 item: {
   id: 1,
   variants: [
    {
     id: 1,
     prices: [
      {
       needle: 100
      },
      {
       needle: 200
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
 }
```

Basicly I want to be able to select all needle values within prices. Could anyone push me in the right direction?

if the prices dimension wouldn't be there I would be able to do the below:

```
item.variants.Select(v => v.needle.ToString()))
```

What I have tried...

```
item.variants.Where(x => x.prices != null)
               .SelectMany(v => 
                 v.prices.Select(p => 
                   p.needle.ToString()
                 ).Distinct()
               )
```

Result should be

```
[0] [string] "100", 
[1] [string] "200"
```

Comment: How would look correct result from this json? What if there were multiple needles with the same price, do you want just unique ones?

Comment: Result should be [0] [string] 100, [1] [string] 200. I just want unique ones.

Comment: @SoptikHa your code is not exactly the same. You're calling `Distinct` after flattening `v.prices` with `SelectMany`. The OP is calling `Distinct` within the `SelectMany`. So, the OP is getting distinct `needle`s within each `variant`, but not the distinct `needles` across all `variant`s. If... that makes sense?

Comment: You're right, I missed it when I wrote that comment. I actually noticed it after a while and deleted my comment, but still thank you for clarification :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var result = structure.variants
                     // Throw away variants without prices
                    .Where(variant => variant.prices != null)
                    // For each variant, select all needle prices (.toString) and flatten it into 1D array
                    .SelectMany(variant => variant.prices.Select(price => price.needle.ToString()))
                    // And choose only unique prices
                    .Distinct();
```

For structure like this:

```
var structure = new Item(
                new Variant(new Price(200), new Price(100), new Price(800)),
                new Variant(new Price(100), new Price(800), new Price(12))
            );
```

is output `[ 200, 100, 800, 12 ]`.

How does it work?

`.SelectMany` basically takes array-inside-array and turns it into normal array. `[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ] => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`, and `.Distinct` throws away duplicate values.

The code I came up with is almost exactly the same as yours. It looks like you are doing `.Distinct` on `.Select`, not on `.SelectMany`. What's the difference? `.Select` selects *one* value (in this case) - it's pointless to call Distinct on it, which drop duplicates. `.SelectMany` selects *many* values - so if you want to call Distinct somewhere, it should be on result of `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```csharp
items.variants
    .Where(v => v.Prices != null)
    .SelectMany(v => v.prices)
    .Select(p => p.needle.ToString())
    .Distinct();
```

`SelectMany` flattens the `prices` arrays to a single `IEnumerable<Price>`.

`Select` projects the `needle` value to an `IEnumerable<string>`.

`Distinct` to get just the distinct `needle` values.

Answer (score 0):

A small push in the right direction might be that you select more than 1 element inside select many and use and iterator parameter of select to get item index later. For example:

```
var result = item.variants
    .Where(x => x.prices != null)
    .SelectMany(o => o.prices.Select(x => new {Type = x.needle.GetType(), Value = x.needle}))
    .Select((o, i) => $"[{i}] [{o.Type}] {o.Value}").ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",\n", result));
```